# RichTextBox insert media file (like video)

Tags: c#, video, richtextbox, media

Is there anyway to insert some media content like video file in richtextbox control?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) which is free. Based on its [Rich Content Features](http://ckeditor.com/about/features#user-rich-content) it supports flash videos so I guess this should work for you.